# angular typescript - show hide tabs when switch language on website

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When i switch language on the website, i want to show or hide one tab, if the language is german then show it, if any other language then hide it, my code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe({next: (event: { lang: string; }) =>{
            if(event.lang && event.lang === 'de'){
                this.tabsArray =  this.tabsArray.filter((tab) => tab.label !== certainPathLabel );
            }
            else{
                const foundLabel = this.tabsArray.find((tab)=>tab.label == certainPathLabel );
                if(!foundLabel) {
                    this.tabsArray.splice(4,0, {label: certainPathLabel , route: this.routeService.generateUrl(certainPatRoute)})      
                }

            }
            this.tabs$.next(this.tabsArray);
        }

    });
}
```

This works only if i select german, the tab is hidden but if i then select any other language i cannot display the tab again no matter what i choose, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the possibility to use a simple observable ?

```js
isGerman$ = this.translate.onLangChange.pipe(
  map({ next: (event: { lang: string; }) } => // Are you sure for { } ?
    event.lang && event.lang === 'de'
  )
);
```

```html
<tabs>
  <tab *ngIf="isGerman$ | async">German</tab>
</tabs>
```

Comment: no, my html looks like this <box-tabs-layout [tabs]="tabs$ | async" (state)="updateState($event)">

Comment: You do not have to change your main array (this.tabsArray). You must use another variable to hold the filtered array (e.g. filteredTabsArray) and then filter and hold the main array and hold it in filteredTabsArray. then call this.tabs$.next(this.filteredTabsArray);